# LINQ similar queries totally different execution time

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have very strange problem with Entity Framework and Linq. My first query looks like this:

```
    from account in context.account
    join access in context.access on account.Id equals access.IdAccount
    join group in context.group on access.IdGroup equals group.Id
    where account.IdUser == idUser
    && access.Date > DateTime(2014,02,21)
    && group.Access > 0
    select access
```

executes without any problems. But the same question after adding additional condition (access.Status > 0) executes very long. After 30 sec it is still running:

```
    from account in context.account
    join access in context.access on account.Id equals access.IdAccount
    join group in context.group on access.IdGroup equals group.Id
    where account.IdUser == idUser
    && access.Status > 0
    && access.Date > DateTime(2014,02,21)
    && group.Access > 0
    select access
```

Status column isn't a computed column. SQL queries returned from

```
    ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)result).ToTraceString();
```

are totally different. Where could be a problem with this additional access.Status condition in query?

Generated SQL queries. Name of columns are different because in LINQ examples they are translated from polish to english. For the first one is:

```
    SELECT
    `Filter1`.`IdDostep`, 
    `Filter1`.`IDKONTO1` AS `IdKonto`, 
    `Filter1`.`IndeksOms`, 
    `Filter1`.`IdGrupa`, 
    `Filter1`.`DataUtw`, 
    `Filter1`.`DataMod`, 
    `Filter1`.`DataOd`, 
    `Filter1`.`DataDo`, 
    `Filter1`.`Znacznik`, 
    `Filter1`.`Kalendarz`, 
    `Filter1`.`Komplet`, 
    `Filter1`.`Access`
    FROM (SELECT
    `Extent1`.`IdKonto`, 
    `Extent1`.`IdAbonenta`, 
    `Extent1`.`NrAbonenta`, 
    `Extent1`.`NrFaktury`, 
    `Extent1`.`DataFaktury`, 
    `Extent1`.`Login`, 
    `Extent1`.`Password`, 
    `Extent1`.`Notatka`, 
    `Extent1`.`IPAdres`, 
    `Extent1`.`Email`, 
    `Extent1`.`LastLogin`, 
    `Extent1`.`LastIP`, 
    `Extent1`.`Session`, 
    `Extent1`.`Regulamin`, 
    `Extent1`.`RegulaminDataAkceptacji`, 
    `Extent1`.`Powiadomienie`, 
    `Extent1`.`Gratis`, 
    `Extent1`.`PrzyEmail`, 
    `Extent1`.`PrzyIdPytanie`, 
    `Extent1`.`PrzyOdpowiedz`, 
    `Extent1`.`PrzyStatus`, 
    `Extent1`.`PrzySesja`, 
    `Extent1`.`IdKod`, 
    `Extent1`.`szerokosc`, 
    `Extent1`.`wysokosc`, 
    `Extent1`.`serwis`, 
    `Extent1`.`Nzam`, 
    `Extent1`.`parent`, 
    `Extent1`.`RegulaminLogowanie`, 
    `Extent1`.`NoBaners`, 
    `Extent1`.`KontoPromocyjne`, 
    `Extent2`.`IdDostep`, 
    `Extent2`.`IdKonto` AS `IDKONTO1`, 
    `Extent2`.`IndeksOms`, 
    `Extent2`.`IdGrupa`, 
    `Extent2`.`DataUtw`, 
    `Extent2`.`DataMod`, 
    `Extent2`.`DataOd`, 
    `Extent2`.`DataDo`, 
    `Extent2`.`Znacznik`, 
    `Extent2`.`Kalendarz`, 
    `Extent2`.`Komplet`, 
    `Extent2`.`Access`
    FROM `konto` AS `Extent1` INNER JOIN `dostep` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`IdKonto` = `Extent2`.`IdKonto`
     WHERE `Extent2`.`DataDo` > @gp1) AS `Filter1` INNER JOIN `grupa` AS `Extent3` ON `Filter1`.`IdGrupa` = `Extent3`.`IdGrupa`
     WHERE (`Filter1`.`NrAbonenta` = @p__linq__0) AND (`Extent3`.`Access` > 0)
```

For the second one is:

```
    SELECT
    `Filter1`.`IdDostep`, 
    `Filter1`.`IDKONTO1` AS `IdKonto`, 
    `Filter1`.`IndeksOms`, 
    `Filter1`.`IdGrupa`, 
    `Filter1`.`DataUtw`, 
    `Filter1`.`DataMod`, 
    `Filter1`.`DataOd`, 
    `Filter1`.`DataDo`, 
    `Filter1`.`Znacznik`, 
    `Filter1`.`Kalendarz`, 
    `Filter1`.`Komplet`, 
    `Filter1`.`Access`
    FROM (SELECT
    `Extent1`.`IdKonto`, 
    `Extent1`.`IdAbonenta`, 
    `Extent1`.`NrAbonenta`, 
    `Extent1`.`NrFaktury`, 
    `Extent1`.`DataFaktury`, 
    `Extent1`.`Login`, 
    `Extent1`.`Password`, 
    `Extent1`.`Notatka`, 
    `Extent1`.`IPAdres`, 
    `Extent1`.`Email`, 
    `Extent1`.`LastLogin`, 
    `Extent1`.`LastIP`, 
    `Extent1`.`Session`, 
    `Extent1`.`Regulamin`, 
    `Extent1`.`RegulaminDataAkceptacji`, 
    `Extent1`.`Powiadomienie`, 
    `Extent1`.`Gratis`, 
    `Extent1`.`PrzyEmail`, 
    `Extent1`.`PrzyIdPytanie`, 
    `Extent1`.`PrzyOdpowiedz`, 
    `Extent1`.`PrzyStatus`, 
    `Extent1`.`PrzySesja`, 
    `Extent1`.`IdKod`, 
    `Extent1`.`szerokosc`, 
    `Extent1`.`wysokosc`, 
    `Extent1`.`serwis`, 
    `Extent1`.`Nzam`, 
    `Extent1`.`parent`, 
    `Extent1`.`RegulaminLogowanie`, 
    `Extent1`.`NoBaners`, 
    `Extent1`.`KontoPromocyjne`, 
    `Extent2`.`IdDostep`, 
    `Extent2`.`IdKonto` AS `IDKONTO1`, 
    `Extent2`.`IndeksOms`, 
    `Extent2`.`IdGrupa`, 
    `Extent2`.`DataUtw`, 
    `Extent2`.`DataMod`, 
    `Extent2`.`DataOd`, 
    `Extent2`.`DataDo`, 
    `Extent2`.`Znacznik`, 
    `Extent2`.`Kalendarz`, 
    `Extent2`.`Komplet`, 
    `Extent2`.`Access`
    FROM `konto` AS `Extent1` INNER JOIN `dostep` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`IdKonto` = `Extent2`.`IdKonto`
     WHERE ((`Extent2`.`Komplet`) > 0) AND (`Extent2`.`DataDo` > @gp1)) AS `Filter1` INNER JOIN `grupa` AS `Extent3` ON `Filter1`.`IdGrupa` = `Extent3`.`IdGrupa`
     WHERE (`Filter1`.`NrAbonenta` = @p__linq__0) AND (`Extent3`.`Access` > 0)
```

Comment: could you add the results of `ToTraceString()`?

Comment: have you compared sql which is generated by queries?

Comment: is `access.Status` indexed ?

Comment: Yes, access.Staus is indexed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem shouldn't be in linq but the underlying execution of the sql statement in the database. Probably the first query executes using just indexes, while the second scans the table.

Suggestion to solve your issue, see the execution plan of both queries, using the ToTraceString() and understand your problem. If you need extra help, post that queryplans and we will give you a hand.

**EDIT:**

As you might see from the sql queries, they aren't that different, they only differ in the inner query filter:

The first query has this:

```
    WHERE  Extent2.datado > @gp1) AS Filter1
```

the second one:

```
    WHERE  ( ( Extent2.komplet ) > 0 ) 
           AND ( Extent2.datado > @gp1 )) AS Filter1
```

So, even though you have everything index doesn't mean they are good indexes. If you have an index for each of the columns SQL might choose only one of them. Probably you'll need to review them. So, like i suggested earlier, check the query execution plan of each and see where's your bottleneck.

Comment: As you can see in sql queries I've added just before, the queries are totally different, while I've added only one column condition. Why this queries are so different?

Comment: @torpederos Are you sure you're posting the correct SQL Query of the linq above? Because the linq has two "dynamic" filters, the `Date` and the `IdUser`, only one is actually passed. Please recheck if your `result` variable is the linq expression

Comment: Your answer was very helpful. I've forget to mention that the whole problem applies to MySql database. When I run query with "explain" I've found that "derived" queries don't use any index and the only solution for this is to try to modify sql query. After a few tries I've found LINQ construction that produces optimal sql query.